# PyTorch: _thnn_nll_loss_forward is not implemented for type torch.LongTensor

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, loss-function

When trying to create a model using PyTorch, when I am trying to implement the loss function `nll_loss`, it is throwing the following error

```py
RuntimeError: _thnn_nll_loss_forward is not implemented for type torch.LongTensor
```

The fit function I have created is:

```py
for epoch in tqdm_notebook(range(1, epochs+1)):
    for batch_idx, (data, targets) in enumerate(train_loader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        net.float()
        output = net(data)
        output_x = output.argmax(dim=2) #to convert (64,50,43) -> (64, 50)
        loss = F.nll_loss(output_x, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_idx % 100 == 0:
            print('Train epochs: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx*len(data), len(ds.data),
                100.*batch_idx / len(ds), loss.item()
            ))
```

Where the output and targets' shape is *(64, 50)* and the dtypes are `torch.int64` for both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the [description](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.nll_loss) of `F.nll_loss`. It expects to get as input not the `argmax` of the prediction (type `torch.long`), but rather the full 64x50x43 prediction vectors (of type `torch.float`). Note that indeed the prediction you provide to `F.nll_loss` has an extra dimension more than the ground truth targets you provide.

In your case, simply remove the argmax:

```
loss = F.nll_loss(output, targets)
```

Comment: I had already tried removing the argmax at then I get this error `RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Double for argument #4 'mat1'
`.

Comment: @thanatoz it seems like you converted your `net` to `float`, but for some reason your `output` is of type `torch.double`.

Comment: What would you suggest. How should I solve this? I found that `nn.GRU(input_size=100, hidden_size=50, dropout=0.5, bidirectional=True, num_layers=2, batch_first=True)` is responsible for this.

Comment: @thanatoz make sure your `data` and hidden states are all of type `torch.float`. Note that [`x.to(torch.float)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to) or [`x.float()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.float) are **not** in-place operations, you need `x = x.to(torch.float)` in order to have `x` as float.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are handling classification task with `43` classes, using batch size of `64` with "sequence length" is `50`.

If so, I believe that you are a little confused of using `argmax()` or `F.log_softmax`. As Shai gave the reference, given `output` is logit values, you might use:

```py
output_x = F.log_softmax(output, dim=2)
loss = F.nll_loss(output_x, targets)
```

It is the correct way of using `nll_loss`, or if you don't want to do `log_softmax`
yourself, you can use `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` instead.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. I did try your suggestion and it runs into following error `RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Double for argument #4 'mat1'
`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, Thanks David.